# Modifying Java Paths when deploying WAR

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, war

I have a webserver that I developed in Eclipse with a local TomCat server. When developing, I often had to run scripts from the command line from my Java code. I just looked at the working directory that Java inside eclipse was working from (was in the Eclipse subdirectory somewhere) and put a ton of files and scripts in here.

Now when creating a WAR those paths are wrong. I'm just not sure how to integrate this all into my project correctly. Should I copy everything into the Eclipse project directory and make the Java 'home' path here - how can I set this up so that the WAR would work when deployed on a webserver?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you should be able to fix this by getting the application path at runtime, then prepending that to your script and file paths. You may also be able to load them as classpath resources. Can you provide an example of how you're using these files and scripts in your application?

Comment: The subdirectory that has all the scripts etc are called by the Webserver classes by using the process builder class. It is used to interface with another java jar which carried out statistical analysis (I can't modify this program), and I wrote a bunch of other shell scripts to read the output of many text and log files that are generated. These are then returned to the webserver classes which for instance, tabulate this data. You can also use the front end of the webserver to start new statistical analysis, which actually means having the Java code call a bash script to run this program.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I copy everything into the Eclipse project directory and make the Java 'home' path here - how can I set this up so that the WAR would work when deployed on a webserver?

That is a bad idea:

- Since you can't change the "current directory" in a Java program, the only way to do that would be to "cd" to the Eclipse project directory and start Tomcat from there.  Yuck!!
- And that's conceptually wrong:

  - Suppose you had two WAR files created in two distinct Eclipse projects.  An application cannot have two different "current" directories.  It makes no sense.
  - What if you want to deploy to a Tomcat on a system that doesn't have the Eclipse projector available to it ...

---

The correct way to solve this is to put all of the requisite files *into* the WAR file, and then access them from your webapp codebase using either webapp relative file paths ... or via the classpath.

Yes, it will entail changing the code of your webapp, but it is the right approach.

Comment: So how exactly do I put everything into the webapp/war? Do I copy the entire other directory into the eclipse project builder, then when exporting as a war it will be packed inside? Even after doing this, the Java files inside my webapp still 'run' from a totally different directory and I'm not sure how this is assigned when bundling as a war file.